# Not uniqueness of a measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ a measurable space and $v,\mu$ two measures such that $\mu\ge v$.

I proved that there exists a measure $\lambda$ such that $\mu=v+\lambda$, and if $v$ is $\sigma$-finite then $\lambda$ is unique.

Now I want to find and example where $v$ is not $\sigma$-finite and such $\lambda$ is not unique.

Does anyone know an example of this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the existences and uniqueness of  $\lambda$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\mu=\nu=$  the counting measure on $\mathbb{R}$, the measure that returns the number of elements if the input is a finite set and $\infty$ if it is an infinite set.

Then you can take $\lambda$ to be the zero measure or also to be the Lebesgue measure, or any measure that is zero on finite sets would work.